# Generator iterator with push back function

Tags: python, iterator, generator

In a compiler project for an LL(1/2) grammar, I have had a need for a generator iterator with a push back function. I have been surprised not to find any perfectly applicable solution (clean, simple, obvious, standard, etc.). On the other hand I was surprised of how easy it was to create exactly what I wanted after I decided to invest a little time.

Here is what I came up with:

```
class Back_pushable_iterator:
    """Class whose constructor takes an iterator as its only parameter, and
    returns an iterator that behaves in the same way, with added push back
    functionality.

    The idea is to be able to push back elements that need to be retrieved once
    more with the iterator semantics. This is particularly useful to implement
    LL(k) parsers that need k tokens of lookahead. Lookahead or push back is
    really a matter of perspective. The pushing back strategy allows a clean
    parser implementation based on recursive parser functions.

    The invoker of this class takes care of storing the elements that should be
    pushed back. A consequence of this is that any elements can be "pushed
    back", even elements that have never been retrieved from the iterator.
    The elements that are pushed back are then retrieved through the iterator
    interface in a LIFO-manner (as should logically be expected).

    This class works for any iterator but is especially meaningful for a
    generator iterator, which offers no obvious push back ability.

    In the LL(k) case mentioned above, the tokenizer can be implemented by a
    standard generator function (clean and simple), that is completed by this
    class for the needs of the actual parser.
    """
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.pushed_back = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.pushed_back:
            return self.pushed_back.pop()
        else:
            return next(self.iterator)

    def push_back(self, element):
        self.pushed_back.append(element)

def main():
    it = Back_pushable_iterator(x for x in range(10))

    x = next(it) # 0
    print(x)
    it.push_back(x)
    x = next(it) # 0
    print(x)
    x = next(it) # 1
    print(x)
    x = next(it) # 2
    y = next(it) # 3
    print(x)
    print(y)
    it.push_back(y)
    it.push_back(x)
    x = next(it) # 2
    y = next(it) # 3
    print(x)
    print(y)

    for x in it:
        print(x) # 4-9

    it.push_back(x)
    y = next(it) # 9
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any feedback is appreciated. A better name? ;-)

Note: I have already posted this code as a very late answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425270/how-to-look-ahead-one-element-in-a-python-generator, but got no feeback.

Comment: I have little time for a deep review, which wouldn't be that long since your code is nicely short. However, have you thoroughly tested the case where the underlying iterator is exhausted, and the user wants to push back?

Comment: @Austin: thanks. I don't know about thoroughly but I added a little test at the end (updated) and it behaves as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to expand on Austin Hastings comment.

According to [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) documentation,

> The intention of the protocol is that once an iterator’s next() method raises StopIteration, it will continue to do so on subsequent calls. Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

It means that once the underlying iterator raises `StopIteration`, your object shall not accept any more push backs.

---

I would call the list `lookahead` rather than `pushed_back`, but it is a matter of taste.

---

Otherwise, LGTM.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get it. Do you think it is reasonable to raise StopIteration for push_back() subsequent calls too? I have updated the code accordingly. When it comes to lookahead, I have actually considered using that name for a method that would look ahead in the iterator (without changing the object's state from a user perspective). Therefore, I will not rename pushed_back to lookahead.

Comment: @nilo I am not sure about `StopIteration` (it is strictly reserved for the `next` call). I would go with a custom exception.

Comment: I think, however, that if you deny push_back after the underlying iteration has stopped the class will not be useful for the intended scope.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected code after review from vnp:

```
class StopPushingBack(Exception):
    pass

class Back_pushable_iterator:
    """Class whose constructor takes an iterator as its only parameter, and
    returns an iterator that behaves in the same way, with added push back
    functionality.

    The idea is to be able to push back elements that need to be retrieved once
    more with the iterator semantics. This is particularly useful to implement
    LL(k) parsers that need k tokens of lookahead. Lookahead or push back is
    really a matter of perspective. The pushing back strategy allows a clean
    parser implementation based on recursive parser functions.

    The invoker of this class takes care of storing the elements that should be
    pushed back. A consequence of this is that any elements can be "pushed
    back", even elements that have never been retrieved from the iterator.
    The elements that are pushed back are then retrieved through the iterator
    interface in a LIFO-manner (as should be logically expected).

    This class works for any iterator but is especially meaningful for a
    generator iterator, which offers no obvious push back ability.

    In the LL(k) case mentioned above, the tokenizer can be implemented by a
    standard generator function (clean and simple), that is completed by this
    class for the needs of the actual parser.

    Once the iterator's next() method raises StopIteration, subsequent calls to
    push_back() will raise StopPushingBack.
    """

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.pushed_back = []
        self.ok_to_push_back = True

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.pushed_back:
            return self.pushed_back.pop()
        else:
            try:
                return next(self.iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                self.ok_to_push_back = False
                raise

    def push_back(self, element):
        if not self.ok_to_push_back:
            raise StopPushingBack
        else:
            self.pushed_back.append(element)

def main():
    it = Back_pushable_iterator(x for x in range(10))

    x = next(it)
    print(x) # 0
    it.push_back(x)
    x = next(it)
    print(x) # 0
    x = next(it)
    print(x) # 1
    x = next(it)
    y = next(it)
    print(x) # 2
    print(y) # 3
    it.push_back(y)
    it.push_back(x)
    x = next(it)
    y = next(it)
    print(x) # 2
    print(y) # 3

    for x in it:
        print(x) # 4-9

    it.push_back(x) # StopPushingBack

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am not too used to defining custom exceptions. Is that fine?

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7 the above code is slightly modified and improved:

- `__next__()` -> `next()`
- `self.iterator = iter(iterator)` - for simpler initiation, for example `PushBackIterator(range(10))` instead `PushBackIterator(x for x in range(10))`
- names of classes

---

```
class PushBackDenied(Exception):
    pass


class PushBackIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iter(iterator)
        self.pushed_back = []
        self.ok_to_push_back = True

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.pushed_back:
            return self.pushed_back.pop()
        else:
            try:
                return next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self.ok_to_push_back = False
            raise

    def push_back(self, element):
        if not self.ok_to_push_back:
            raise PushBackDenied
        else:
            self.pushed_back.append(element)


it = PushBackIterator(range(10))
for i, x in enumerate(it):
   print i, x
   if i % 2:
       it.push_back(x)

0 0
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 3
6 3
7 4
8 4
9 5
10 5
11 6
12 6
13 7
14 7
15 8
16 8
17 9
18 9
```

Comment: some explanation wouldn't hurt

Comment: I just rewrite the code above for Python 2.7 ```def __next__()``` -> ```def next()``` and added ```iter(iterator)``` in ```__init__()``` for simpler initiation.
Example of that usage posted below.
Thank you for your question, I tried to understand better what I did ;-)

Comment: added description of changes

Comment: and, sorry, I missed the site, thought of being at stackoverflow ;-)